# PHP - Can't Get Regex To Work: Undefined Offset

Tags: php, regex

For some reason I can't parse this regex, which works in a live demonstration.

I took the code from the live demo, pasted it into a new PHP file, saved it and ran it in my server.

Does anybody know why it doesn't work and can explain me why?
It's literally the same code. :\

```
$str = <<< STR
    sbmt_btn.hide();
    $(this).load(urlStr, data, function (response, innerstatus, xhr) {
        status = innerstatus;
        pb.hide();
        sbmt_btn.show();
        if (status == "error") {
            var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
            $(this).html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        }
        if ($('#NoMoreSearchForYou').get(0)) {
            $('.ui-dialog-buttonset').hide();
        }
        else if ($('#MoreSearchForYou').length > 0) {
            $('.ui-dialog-buttonset').show();
        }
        else {
            $('.ui-dialog-buttonset').hide();
        }
    });
},
STR;

preg_match('~\$\(this.+[\s\S]*hide\(\);[\s\S]{49};~', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0]);
```

Original code that works: [live demo](https://3v4l.org/fKIqa)

The error shown as in image:

[image: here]

My `phpinfo`: [here](https://www.filedropper.com/)

Comment: I forgot to add some things. Please don't downvote my question. :\

Thanks for reminding me, though.

Comment: On eval the `[\s\S]{49};` is breaking it. https://eval.in/622310 Not sure the cause. You should add your code here. (Oh i changed the variable assignment too because `eval` was highlighting it strangely and thought it was an issue. It wasn't, functioned the same there)

Comment: I think since you knew the fixed length of the end part of chars, that's mean you know what things to grab, this might be the simpler one `\$\(this[\\s\\S]+hide\(\);[\\s\\S]+\}\);`. Notice, I escape the `\s` and `\S` that's probably your issue.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot.

It worked. :)

Comment: I put it as answer then. Wasn't sure beforehand since my regex knowledge sucks.

Comment: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash of regex syntax such as `\s` as it won't appear properly in string. So it should be `\\s`.

```
preg_match('~\$\(this.+[\\s\\S]*hide\(\);[\\s\\S]{49};~', $str, $matches);
```

And, I think since you knew the fixed length of the end part of chars, that's mean you know what things to grab, this might be the simpler one.

```
preg_match('~\$\(this[\\s\\S]+hide\(\);[\\s\\S]+\}\);~', $str, $matches);
```

Comment: @chris85 PHP `preg_*` uses string as the argument for regex pattern. And the way quote present in the string will be escaped at runtime.

Comment: What is the second backslash doing? https://3v4l.org/AhSk0 The regex101 didn't really show that I guess

Comment: If you think you have to escape the backslash for `\s` how would you escape an escape ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is that you have a fixed width requirement at the end.

Between `\(\)` **[\s\S]{49}** and `;`

This is never a good idea, especially if `[\S\s]` span's lines.
You never know how some crappy web site tester's handle CRLF translation, so don't do this.

A simple test will show this. Using a capture group, and changing it to
use a variable greedy quantifier `\(\)([\s\S]+);` we get:

```
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 895 , len 51 ) 

                        }
                    })
```

This is with CRLF line translation.

---

If we turn *OFF* translation (only LF's now), we get:

```
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 878 , len 49 ) 

                        }
                    })
```

And there is your `49`.

---

Conclusion's:

Either change it to
1. `\$\(this.+[\s\S]*hide\(\);[\s\S]+;`
or
2. `\$\(this.+[\s\S]*hide\(\);[\s\S]{49,51};`

---

You are better off using `1.` because it doesn't make sense to mold
an expression around possible editing, or some generated output *formatting*.